# handling extension less urls: how to install QFE extension?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5

So I've found an [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/04/01/asp-net-4-0-enables-routing-of-extensionless-urls-without-impacting-static-requests.aspx) how asp.net 4.0 can skip handling of static resources (.css, .js, images), it mentions QFE extension for IIS, that is [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368). Problem is, that when I', trying to install it (on windows 7 x64), it says

```
The update is not applicable to your computer.
```

Love the obscurity of error message, I could think of several reasons why is this so:

1. I have it already (may be it was included in SP1, may be something else, file versions do not match with listed on update, my hwebcore.dll version is 7.5.7600.16385), but it does not work (how to check that?)
2. I has some dependencies, how to find out which?
3. Broken update on MS site, is there fixed version, how can i get it?
4. Other?

UPDATE: As I mentioned, dll's version is different from provided in hotfix page (my is 7.5.7600.16385 and theirs 7.5.7600.20654).

Comment: You can check versions of affected files (list is given in the QFE link) and check if you already have this installed on your machine or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like update is not needed (not sure why - because .net update/windows sp1/or smth else).

Update:

as long as I have production server with Win 2008 and IIS 7.0, update was required and installed successfully, so I don't have enough data, but it may that IIS 7.5 does not require that update anymore.